# mysql select with sub query where closure

Tags: mysql, sql

users have multiple location, i want to select all users who have at least one common location to authenticated user.

f.e

```
select * from users as user where 
( select location_id from user_locations where user_id = auth()->user->id ) 
'has common operator' 
( select location_id from user_locations where user_id = user.id )
```

---

i want to compare two array if they have common elements, but i think mysql has no such function

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_locations ul ON ul. user_id = u.id

WHERE ul.location_id IN (
    SELECT location_id 
    FROM user_locations 
    WHERE user_id = auth()->user->id
)
```

Comment: this wont work without selecting distinct , cos it will select same user as many times as they have common location_id. it is also not optimal way and do not want to use join.

Comment: i want to compare to array if they have common elements, but i think mysql has no such function

Comment: That LEFT JOIN executes as an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work, try it please.

```
select *
from users as user
where 
exists (
    select 1 
    from user_locations ul
    where ul.user_id = user.id
    and exists (
        select 1
        from user_locations ul_in
        where ul_in.user_id = auth()->user->id
        and ul_in.location_id = ul.location_id 
    )
)
```